# How to create docker image for ASP.Net Web API SDK 6.0 application (Platform Target x86)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I have created an ASP.NET Web API application, which is targeted to x86.

In the Docker file, I have used:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
```

When I build, docker image using docker desktop, getting the below error -

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException.
```

This is an x86 targeted application, hence the issue.

How to resolve this? Thank you.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication4.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication4.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you share your docker file?

Comment: Included in the main content

Comment: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0` is 64-bit Linux. [There's no 32-bit image except for ARM](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet). Why are you targeting 32-bit explicitly?

Comment: In my project, we referenced one 32-bit dll for some other functionality. Do we have any work around for this?